# LifecycleConfiguration -- The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using AWSSDK.dll version  2.1.3.0
i am trying to add new lifecycle rule
here is the code

```
IAmazonS3 _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("A*****************Z", "a*************b", bucketRegion);

        // Retrieve current configuration
        var configuration =   _s3Client.GetLifecycleConfiguration(
       new GetLifecycleConfigurationRequest
       {
           BucketName = bucketName
       }).Configuration;

        
        
            //Adding new Rule
            configuration.Rules.Add(new LifecycleRule
            {
                
                Id = "ATam",  
                Prefix = "ATam/PanCake QA/Avaniti/",
                Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
                {
                    Days = 3650
                },
                Transition = new LifecycleTransition()
                {
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Glacier,
                    Days = 14
                },
                Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
            });



        PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest request = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Configuration = configuration
        };
        var response = _s3Client.PutLifecycleConfiguration(request);
```

But i am getting this exception
An unhandled exception of type 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception' occurred in AWSSDK.dll  Additional information: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
Can anyone let me know  where i am going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-dot-net.html

Comment: Yes, i had  went through that url it works , but my application uses   AWSSDK.dll version 2.1.3.0 how can i make it work

Comment: Whats the difference?  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the working and non working request.  Do you have the schema?  Did the schema change?  Did the encryption mode SSL/TLS change?  Did you do a clean build when upgrading?

Comment: If i have to use the latest DLL then i have to check other functionalities to make sure it works properly. i dont have the schema

Comment: The code which i have given was working but it suddenly stopped.

Comment: I'm suspecting the SSL/TLS encryption is failing.  I would check with sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and get the http status.  It should be 200 OK.  If you are getting a different status then give me the error number.  Many servers recently discontinued TLS 1.0.  So your old dll may not work.

Comment: Look what I found : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-to-become-the-minimum-for-all-aws-fips-endpoints/

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.                                                                                           Status --  ProtocolError  , Error Code  --MalformedXML

Comment: Since code was working an recently stopped my best guess is you are still using TLS 1.1 and have to upgrade to 1.2.  To fix it is a combination of windows and net library.  You have to have a version of windows that supports 1.2 which may require adding security upgrades to windows.  So using an httpwebrequest you need to set System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.  If you version of net doesn't have the enumeration tls12 then you have to set a windows registry setting to force tls1.2 instead of tls1.1.

Comment: I added this     System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  still not working

Comment: To make it work i had to  use this   AWSSDK.S3    installed it from nuget package but could not  find a solution for the old AWSSDK version

Comment: It may be the browser settings.  Are you still getting 400 error?  What browser (content type header  in request) is selected in the sniffer data?  Also check following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/enforcing-tls.html

Comment: It may be the browser settings.  Are you still getting 400 error?  What browser (content type header  in request) is selected in the sniffer data?  Also check following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/enforcing-tls.html.  You need the right version of Net/Core, right version of Windows, and make sure the version 1.2 is being used (not 1.1).  Use only System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 (remove System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11).

Comment: I am using this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-dot-net.html      which u had suggested could not find a reason for that

Comment: Look at the developer guide in my last response.  You are using a version from 2014 that probably will not support TLS1.2.  See the version on this page : https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK/

Comment: Following page says version 2 was depreciated in 2015 to get ready for TLS 1.2 : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/

Comment: When i use  AWSSDK.Core (3.3.0.0)
and AWSSDK.S3 (3.3.0.0)
dll code works and it uses 
Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)

But when i use  AWSSDK  version 2.3.55.2
it uses 
Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LifecycleTransition properties Days and Storage Class.

```
LifecycleConfiguration newConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
    {
        Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
        {
            new LifecycleRule
                    {
                         Id = "some id here",
                         Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
                         {
                             LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate()
                             {
                                
                             }
                         },
                         Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
                         Transitions = new List<LifecycleTransition>
                         {
                              new LifecycleTransition
                              {
                                   Days = 0,
                                   StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Glacier
                              }
                          },
                         Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
                         {
                               Days = 1
                         }
                    }
        }
    };
```