# GRPC .Net Core server & C++ client: Https connection fails, "No common application protocol between client/server"

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, grpc, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to get a GRPC server (written in .NET core) and client (written in C++) to communicate over a SSL/TLS-secured channel.

The server targets "netcoreapp3.1", and depends on "Grpc.AspNetCore" version 2.28.0. The server code itself is basically copied [from the official grpc repo's examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/dd72d6a38ab2984fd224aa8ed53686dc0153b9da/testassets/InteropTestsWebsite/Startup.cs). The `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` are not too interesting on their own & probably aren't the problems, so I just uploaded them to [a gist](https://gist.github.com/anlsh/20b41d9ca5aa7f9c84a6c05e1722d7fb) (do note the call to `UseHttps` though).  Everything builds, and a toy .NET core GRPC client (sources for that [here](https://gist.github.com/anlsh/a15adf2244a5e3fba74c4df0520e1f40)) connects over HTTPS just fine

Unfortunately, I need to be using a C++ client to make the connection. Theoretically, the process is simple: get the .pfx file corresponding to the certificate passed to the `UseHttps` call, use it to create a `server.crt` [via openssl](https://nerdia.net/2018/06/16/how-to-convert-a-certificate-pfx-file-to-crt-key-using-openssl/), and use that to create a secure channel for the C++ client like so:

```
grpc::SslCredentialsOptions sslOpts{};
sslOpts.pem_root_certs = file_to_string(path_to_server_crt);
auto creds = grpc::SslCredentials(sslOpts);
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50052", creds);
```

I've used the client successfully with a C++ grpc server, so there's no lingering bugs on that side either. When I point it at my .NET core server though, things break. The client side info isn't interesting, just a GRPC error 14. When the server is set to log things at `Trace` though, something pops out

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2] 
  Connection id "0HM6UG4PBICBP" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[1]
      Connection id "0HM6UG4PBICBP" started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090367): No common application protocol exists between the client and the server. Application protocol negotiation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
// Some detailed stack trace, pretty sure it's garbage
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[2]
    Connection id "0HM6UG4PBICBP" stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
    Connection id "0HM6UG4PBICBP" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully
```

`No common application protocol exists between the client and the server`, that's certainly interesting: the server must be rejecting whatever protocol the C++ client is trying to use (TLS 1.2, from some googling?). How can I get them talking to each other over a common protocol?

**Note 1**: I should mention that the C++ client is being compiled/run from WSL 1 (Ubuntu 18.04) whereas the server is being run on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

**Note 2**: The discussion here [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131712/netframework-4-6-2-client-to-net-core-3-1-server-grpc-client-calls-failure) relevant, but ultimately doesn't lead to anything useful.

Comment: FTR this was already responded to as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later submitted another question with more details, and with an "answer." You can check that out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478939/https-grpc-connections-from-c-core-clients-to-net-core-server-tls-handshake-fa)